# Comparing Query Result With Table and Retrieve Specific Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

My Query

```
SELECT
    stoMast.sStockistCode,
    stoMast.sStateName,
    stoMast.sDivision,
    stateMap.sRMCode
FROM
    tblRSM_State_Mapping stateMap
INNER JOIN
    tblStockistMaster stoMast ON
    stateMap.sStateName = stoMast.sStateName
WHERE 
    stateMap.sRMCode = 'MCNE04001' 
    and 
    stoMast.sDivision = 'CIDIS'

except

select 
    sStockistCode,
    sStateName,
    sDivision,
    sRMCode
From
    tblEntry
```

[image]

Again I would like to compare the query result columns

- `sStockistCode`
- `sStateName`
- `sDivision`

with `tblStockistMaster` with the same fields

- `sStockistCode`
- `sStateName`
- `sDivision`
  and retrieve the STOCKIST NAME.

Don't know how to compare the above query result with the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use following SQL code used with [CTE](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/article.aspx?articleid=18) expression

```
;with cte as (
    SELECT
        stoMast.sStockistCode,
        stoMast.sStateName,
        stoMast.sDivision,
        stateMap.sRMCode
    FROM
        tblRSM_State_Mapping stateMap
    INNER JOIN
        tblStockistMaster stoMast ON
        stateMap.sStateName = stoMast.sStateName
    WHERE 
        stateMap.sRMCode = 'MCNE04001' 
        and 
        stoMast.sDivision = 'CIDIS'

    except

    select 
        sStockistCode,
        sStateName,
        sDivision,
        sRMCode
    From
        tblEntry
)
select
cte.*,
sm.sStockistName
from cte
left join tblStockistMaster as sm
    on sm.sStockistCode  = cte.sStockistCode  and
       sm.sStateName  = cte.sStateName and
       sm.sDivision = cte.sDivision
```

Comment: Thank you, This works fine.  Can you please tell how to get selected column as output?  Currently it results 4 columns.  I would like to get only sStockistCode and sStateName from it.

Comment: There is cte.* and sm.sStockistName columns in the SELECT list of the query. Instead of CTE.*, you can identify each column like cte.sStockistCode, cte.sStateName, etc.

Comment: Got it!.  Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

```
-- I retrieve the stockist Name
SELECT
    stoMast.sStockistName,
FROM
    tblRSM_State_Mapping stateMap
INNER JOIN
    tblStockistMaster stoMast
        ON stateMap.sStateName = stoMast.sStateName
-- I'm joining table entry If I can match
LEFT JOIN
    tblEntry tbl
        on tbl.sStockistCode = stoMast.sStockistName
        AND tbl.sStateName = stoMast.sStateName
        AND tbl.sDivision = stoMast.sDivision
        AND tbl.sRMCode = stateMap.sRMCode
WHERE 
    stateMap.sRMCode = 'MCNE04001' 
    and stoMast.sDivision = 'CIDIS'
-- And The the exept thing, I don't want that got a match with  the tableentry
    AND COALESCE(tbl.sStockistCode, tbl.sStateName, tbl.sDivision, tbl.sRMCode) is null
```

I expect it is what you wanted to get. On another way please help us understand wht you come from (tables and idea of what data can be in) and the result you want. Will be easier to create a query.

Comment: I tested it and is not getting the desired result.  I know its hard to understand the requirement based on the given sql code.  But it is a combination of 3 table matching query which I written with my limited knowledge with sql.  I am sure you will simplify it but I need to explain it properly.  If you have time then inform me so that I can update the post with detailed info.